# Дупло и диплом, происхождение

Tags: этимология

Почему такие разные значения у слов, произошедших от одного - ***du̯eiplom*** "сложенное вдвое".

Comment: Any reference about etymology of *дупло*?

Comment: Почему такие разные значения у слов, имеющих общее происхождение - это вопрос который можно как угодно широко трактовать - общее происхождение может быть на уровне PIE и слова могут иметь совершенно разное значение. Кроме того, мы озвучиваете гипотезу и не подтверждаете ещё ничем.

Comment: Т. е. это вы сейчас утверждаете, что русск. _дупло_ и _два_ восходят к одному корню?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В словаре Макса Фасмера в [этимологии слова "дупло"](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/39300/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE) не упоминается "сложенное вдвое", только "пустой, полый":

> **дупло**
>   дупло́ укр. дупло́, ст.-слав. доупина σπήλαιον (Супр.), русск.цслав. дупль "пустой, полый", болг. ду́пъл "полый", сербохорв. ду́пља "дупло", словен. dúpǝlj "полый", dúplo "дупло", чеш. doupa, doupě ж. – то же, польск. dupa "задница", dupel м. "дупло". Другая ступень чередования: польск. dziupɫo "дупло, отверстие в дереве". Родственно лтш. duplis, dupis "посуда для соли или сала", ср.-в.-н. tobel "углубление, лощина". Из и.-е. *dhoup- наряду с *dhoub- : *dhub- в дебрь, дно; см. Бернекер 1, 238; Брюкнер 104; М. - Э. 1, 518; Преобр. 1, 202 и сл.; Вандриес, MSL 18, 308; Торп 202.
>   *Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.*

Answer (score 6):

**Дупло** - это славянское слово означающее полость, или вроде того, **диплом** - произошло от греческого *diploma*. Эти слова не имеют ничего общего ни в фонетике, ни в этимологии.

Comment: Кстати, одно слово может быть заимствовано дважды с разными значениями, как например "стол" и "стул".

Comment: @Artemix В этимологии слова _стол_, в отличие от _стула_, не числится никаких заимствований.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Подскажете источник? Я прочел об этом в какой-то бумажной книге, поэтому свою ссылку дать не могу.

Comment: Я на 99.999% уверен что это не тот случай. Скорее всего греческий язык влиял в той или иной степени на старо или даже прото славянский, но два этих слова настолько разные по значению, что родство, на мой взгляд, невозможно.

Comment: @Artemix На что источник? Общепринятая теория, что _стол_ родственен _стелить_ / _стлать_, заимствований не предполагает в принципе.

Comment: @Artemix: a better example would be *кристалл/хрусталь*

Answer (score -7):

Разбирая этимологию слов, иногда попадаешь на слова, которые в своем происхождении имеют нормальный смысл, а в принятом ныне толковании неприличны, или наоборот.  Чтобы понять этимологию слова, следует подобрать максимальное количество похожих слов и не только в русском языке, но и в других индоевропейских языках и попытаться понять, какой же смысл их всех объединяет. Возьмем, к примеру , простое русское слово « дупло». Откуда это слово взялось? Подбираем похожие по звучанию слова:
-du(литовское)- два;
-дубль- второй экз. чего-то;
-дуплет-выстрел одновременно из двух стволов ружья- двухстволки;
-дупель-двойная кость домино ( пусто-пусто, пять-пять.и т.д.)
-dupa( польский яз., русский аналог , простите, жопа)- т.е. двуединая конструкция.
А, теперь, на что похоже дупло, особенно не очень большое? Да на выход прямой кишки! Присмотритесь и Вы убедитесь, что слово « дупло» происходит от слова « dupa» (жопа), а последнее от слова « два». А дальше начинается юмор: истолкуйте фразу:» у меня в зубе дупло!

Comment: Про связь с "дупой" есть у Фасмера (в принятом ответе), остальное не по теме.

Comment: Для Artemix: я- этимолог - любитель. потому не претендую числиться знатоком этимологии. Но, может ли неискушенный , но любознательный человек, понять происхождение какого - нибудь слова, прочитав Ваше или Фармера толкование, если Вы даете перечень , вероятно, однокоренных слов,а  дальше , как в той песне:" догадайся, мол, сама!" Я, стараюсь построить цепочку от

Comment: В продолжение к предыдущему:слова или понятия исходного до слова, которое мы хотим понять

Comment: В самом жанре публицистического ответа (эмоционального, с риторическими вопросами) нет ничего плохого, просто он не подходит для этого сайта. Здесь ценятся ответы краткие и по существу (как статьи в Википедии).